# Filter REST API by Date

Tags: javascript, rest, date, sharepoint

If I have a date field within a SharePoint list, how would I format a REST call that filters based on the date column being greater than today's date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint stores dates in the ISO string format, so use a new Date object and the toISOString method to get today, then append it to the URI as a greater or greater equal...

```
"/_api/lists/listname/items?$filter=Modified ge '" + new Date().toISOString() + "'"
```

Modify listname and Modified to be whatever list and column you're looking at.